# Tkinter Listboxes resetting each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In one window of my Tkinter program, I have two Listboxes displaying simple lists of data options for multiple selection. I have the following code:

```
floor_box = Listbox(form, selectmode="multiple")
floor_box.grid(row=0, column=1)
for i in range(3):
    floor_box.insert(END, str(i+1))
floor_box.config(height=3)
floor_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda _: floor_selection.set([floor_box.get(i) for i in floor_box.curselection()]))

type_selection = StringVar()
type_box = Listbox(form, selectmode="multiple")
type_box.grid(row=1, column=1)
for i in range(len(ROOM_TYPES)):
    type_box.insert(END, ROOM_TYPES[i])
type_box.config(height=len(ROOM_TYPES))
type_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda _: type_selection.set([type_box.get(i) for i in type_box.curselection()]))


def b():
    print(floor_selection.get())
    print(type_selection.get())

Button(window, command=b).pack()
```

Obviously I have omitted the definitions of the frames, window etc. As can be seen, I have two Listboxes, and a temporarily-placed Button to log the selections in each box. When I click the button, only the values selected in the box I adjusted most recently are displayed; the other box has no selections displayed. It seems that only one box can store a set of selections at once despite them using different variables to store their selections.

How can I stop the boxes resetting each other? Any help would be greatly appreciated.